# Succeeds in building rodeo 0.4.3 but fails to run with ubuntu 15.04

Tags: python

I have build rodeo a data oriented ide for python:

```
$ sudo pip install rodeo -U
The directory '/home/jeanpat/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/jeanpat/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already up-to-date: rodeo in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: mistune in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from rodeo)
Requirement already up-to-date: ipython>=3.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from rodeo)
Requirement already up-to-date: docopt in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from rodeo)
Requirement already up-to-date: pyzmq>=13 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from rodeo)
Requirement already up-to-date: Flask>=0.10.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from rodeo)
Requirement already up-to-date: Werkzeug>=0.7 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Flask>=0.10.1->rodeo)
Requirement already up-to-date: Jinja2>=2.4 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Flask>=0.10.1->rodeo)
Requirement already up-to-date: itsdangerous>=0.21 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Flask>=0.10.1->rodeo)
Requirement already up-to-date: markupsafe in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Jinja2>=2.4->Flask>=0.10.1->rodeo)
```

Then when rodeo is run from terminal, the things go wrong:

```
~$ rodeo .

 _______      ___   ______   ________    ___    
|_   __ \   .'   `.|_   _ `.|_   __  | .'   `.  
  | |__) | /  .-.  \ | | `. \ | |_ \_|/  .-.  \ 
  |  __ /  | |   | | | |  | | |  _| _ | |   | | 
 _| |  \ \_\  `-'  /_| |_.' /_| |__/ |\  `-'  / 
|____| |___|`.___.'|______.'|________| `.___.'  

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
  URL: http://localhost:5000/
  DIRECTORY: /home/jeanpat
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

(process:13719): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
[ERROR]: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rodeo/rodeo.py", line 71, in home
    file_tree=file_tree, version=__version__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/templating.py", line 128, in render_template
    context, ctx.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/templating.py", line 110, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 969, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 742, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rodeo/templates/index.html", line 34, in top-level template code
    {% include 'bottom-right.html' %}
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rodeo/templates/bottom-right.html", line 17, in top-level template code
    <a id="file-{{ f.dirname }}" data-parnet-slug="{{ f.parentslug }}" data-dirname="{{ f.dirslug }}" href="#" class="list-group-item {{ f.parentslug }} showdir">
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Firefox says **Internal server error**

Comment: You have error in index or bottom-right.html file. ..please post that also with the same line as shown in debug error log

Comment: after typing in a terminal: "rodeo ." , firefox opens a page at localhost:5000 with the message:"Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application." . Is it what do you mean?

Comment: The error log shows the `bottom-right` file name which is causing the server to overload. So I asked you to put that file contents with the line that displays in error log . this is shown at the bottom of the log!

Comment: Looks like at least one of `f.f.dirname`, `f.parentslug`, or `f.dirslug`, is a byte string and contains at least one character outside of ASCII.

Comment: This is an issue with jinja/flask not liking non-ascii characters. I will figure out how to do this and push out a fix.

Comment: Do you have non-ascii filenames?

Comment: I'm not sure if this fixes the entire issue, but have a look here: https://github.com/yhat/rodeo/commit/df824e6ed3d467a303dcd0c6871e18cb7603e4a0.

If you install 0.4.2, you'll get these changes. It won't be any worse!

Comment: here is bottom-right.html https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-YDFMbEy1grRFRIREVhOEFyZms/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Same probleme with rodeo 0.4.2

Comment: Still can't run rodeo 0.4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When run from a terminal pointing to /home, rodeo failed to run:

```
jeanpat@jeanpat-WA50SHQ:~$ cd ~
jeanpat@jeanpat-WA50SHQ:~$ rodeo .
```

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position
>   3: ordinal not in range(128)

The solution was to create a fresh directory and to start rodeo from it:

```
mkdir RodeoDir
cd RodeoDir/

RodeoDir$ rodeo .

 _______      ___   ______   ________    ___    
|_   __ \   .'   `.|_   _ `.|_   __  | .'   `.  
  | |__) | /  .-.  \ | | `. \ | |_ \_|/  .-.  \ 
  |  __ /  | |   | | | |  | | |  _| _ | |   | | 
 _| |  \ \_\  `-'  /_| |_.' /_| |__/ |\  `-'  / 
|____| |___|`.___.'|______.'|________| `.___.'  

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
  URL: http://localhost:5000/
  DIRECTORY: /home/jeanpat/App/RodeoDir
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

(process:7102): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
```

Answer (score 0):

This really belongs in a comment, but I don't have the rep for it, sorry...

But I experienced exactly the same failure.  Had Rodeo installed via pip on osx and it was working for a while (except that raw_input() would quietly crash the whole thing), then a) broke ipython notebook independently by trying to change the default file location, 2) uninstalled and reinstalled ipython, but 3) somehow rodeo got broken in all of this.  And I also got similar errors with respect to bottom-right.html, although it picked a differently seemingly random line to claim it couldn't understand the ascii in.  (As I recall, the character it claimed to be confused by was an 'a' -- seriously.)

Then it randomly came back the next day.  I suspect that killing and restarting the terminal helped.  So you might try that, just as a start.